# Users unique across all tenants [ABP.IO]

Tags: multi-tenant, abp

Anyone knows if its possible to create users unique across all tenants?

Explain.

User1 creates in tenant1
User1 creates in tenant2.

This approach is the "by default" approach of the framework.

We want to know if there's a solutions to register a user1 in tenant1, and when user1 try to register in tenant2 return an error of "Users exists"

we dont care about if a user already exists in a tenant. Is much easier for us this approach and we can loggin users directly in the application without select a tenant in the login page.

For the tenant admins we have already implemented a solutions with the admin + tenantName, so never be the same user across the tenants (in admin case)

i have been searching across the official docs, here in stackoverflow, and searching in the support forum of abp, but i didnt found anything that answer this question (and if there's something that resolves this, ill be so gratefull to share that with me)

Thanks in advice!

Regards, Jesús.

trying to avoid implementing all the tenant function by myself

Answer (score 0):

No, by default a user can not be a member of multiple tenants. Which means there is no restriction to check if the user with same name/username/email/whatever field you want it to be unique exist or not.

You need to add **custom logic** for it. Also you may want to consider each tenant can have their own database so you will need to query over their database aswell to check if the user exist or not before registering it.